How to use SDMX to get M2 money data from ECB?
I need to fetch data from following 2 links for my analysis :

https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets/BSI/BSI.M.U2.Y.V.M20.X.1.U2.2300.Z01.E
https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets/RTD/RTD.M.JP.Y.M_M2.J

I have never worked with SDMX library before and I am having trouble understanding the documentation. According to my understanding from this link, I tried to put the following code together but it is not working, I get 404 error.
resource = 'data'           # The resource for data queries is always 'data'
flowRef ='BSI'              # Dataflow describing the data that needs to be returned
key = 'M.U2.Y.V.M20.X.1.U2.2300.Z01.E'  # series key for M2 euro area

# Define the parameters
parameters = {
    'startPeriod': '2010-01-01',  # Start date of the time series
    'endPeriod': '2024-07-20',  # End of the time series
    'detail' : 'dataonly' 
}

request_url = entrypoint + resource + '/'+ flowRef + '/' + key
response = requests.get(request_url, params=parameters)
print(response)

I also tried the following code after seeing - how to download data from ECB using pandaSDMX?
datamessage = sdmx.Request('ECB').data(
    resource_id='BSI',
    key='M.U2.Y.V.M20.X.1.U2.2300.Z01.E', 
    params=dict(startPeriod='2010-04-01', endPeriod='2024-07-20'),
)

df = sdmx.to_pandas(datamessage)


With the sdmx1 package (a more actively maintained fork of pandaSDMX), this appears to work:
import sdmx

# A client for talking to the ECB data source
ECB = sdmx.Client("ECB")

# Make the request; returns a DataMessage object
dm = ECB.data(
    "BSI",
    key="M.U2.Y.V.M20.X.1.U2.2300.Z01.E",
    params=dict(startPeriod='2010-04-01', endPeriod='2024-07-20'),                                                )

# Show its contents
print(dm)

This prints the following; DataSet (1) indicates there is 1 data set in the message:
<sdmx.DataMessage>
  <Header>
    id: 'e70b6956-36bf-44ce-a41d-5bf5ad23a4fb'
    prepared: '2024-07-22T11:37:32.306000+02:00'
    sender: <Agency ECB>
    source: 
    test: False
  response: <Response [200]>
  DataSet (1)
  dataflow: <DataflowDefinition (missing id)>
  observation_dimension: <Dimension TIME_PERIOD>

Convert that one data set to a pandas data frame:
df = sdmx.to_pandas(dm.data[0])

print(df)

This shows the following:
FREQ  REF_AREA  ADJUSTMENT  BS_REP_SECTOR  BS_ITEM  MATURITY_ORIG  DATA_TYPE  COUNT_AREA  BS_COUNT_SECTOR  CURRENCY_TRANS  BS_SUFFIX  TIME_PERIOD
M     U2        Y           V              M20      X              1          U2          2300             Z01             E          2010-04         8264769.0
                                                                                                                                      2010-05         8283636.0
                                                                                                                                      2010-06         8313274.0
                                                                                                                                      2010-07         8330970.0
                                                                                                                                      2010-08         8368241.0
                                                                                                                                                        ...    
                                                                                                                                      2024-01        15069880.0
                                                                                                                                      2024-02        15102093.0
                                                                                                                                      2024-03        15136629.0
                                                                                                                                      2024-04        15144918.0
                                                                                                                                      2024-05        15204934.0
Name: value, Length: 170, dtype: float64

Per the key you are using, only one value is selected and returned for every dimension except the last one, TIME_PERIOD.
